# Extreme slow queries after upgrading from 5.6 to 5.7

Tags: php, mysql

When upgrading a mySQL server from 5.6 to 5.7 it seems that a forum running on vbb5 became extremely slow.    Looking at the slow query files it seems row scanning has became much more slower than before.

Below a typical forum query which ran before around 1 to 3 seconds and now runs between 30 an 75 seconds.   Node and closure tables each hold 11 to 13 million records.  I have performed table optimisation on both tables.

```
# Query_time: 56.239686  Lock_time: 0.000452 Rows_sent: 500  Rows_examined: 672441
SELECT DISTINCT node.starter AS nodeid
                        FROM node as node
                        LEFT JOIN node AS starter ON starter.nodeid = IF(node.starter = 0, node.nodeid, node.starter)
                                JOIN closure AS closure  ON node.nodeid = closure.child
                        WHERE node.contenttypeid <> 30 AND
                                closure.parent = '47' AND
                                node.nodeid <> closure.parent AND
                                node.inlist = 1 AND
                                node.contenttypeid <> '15' AND
                                node.protected <> '1'
AND (node.public_preview = 1 OR  ( ( (  (starter.parentid IN (13,22,1,2,24,27,33,47,49,62,14,25,28,32,50,52,70,15,29,31,40,44,63,69,6,16,37,38,43,46,51,53,17,30,39,54,55,67,12,18,23,26,34,42,45,20,21,41,48,56,61,82,80,72,79,77,78,76,75,74,68,73,3629857,3654649) ) AND node.showapproved > 0 AND node.viewperms > 1 AND node.showpublished > 0 ))
 OR starter.parentid = 9 AND node.userid IN (0)))


                        ORDER BY starter.created DESC,node.nodeid ASC
                        LIMIT 500
```

I have played a bith with my.cnf settings but still am negative towards performance boosts:

```
performance-schema=0
symbolic-links=0
performance-schema=0
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
innodb_file_per_table=1
max_allowed_packet=268435456
open_files_limit=10000
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 256M
#tmp_table_size = 50M
#max_heap_table_size = 40M
join_buffer_size= 256K
query_cache_size = 128M
query_cache_type = 1
```

Any hints what i should be looking at?

Comment: Have you tuned this query at all, e.g. by adding or more indices to the right columns/tables?

Comment: The default installation does include multiple indexes on both closure and node table.  Which one would expect?

Comment: Run `EXPLAIN <query>` on both servers? And post all tables structures involved in the question `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table>`

Comment: Try turning off block nested loop from the  [optimizer switch](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_optimizer_switch)